# MongoDB is presenting an 'ETIMEOUT' error

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB Atlas was working fine at one time. Now I have not been able to connect for a time. I’ve looked at other solutions here on this forum as well as others.

I’m getting the aforementioned error using the application connection string, the MongoDB Compass app connection string as well as the MongoDB shell connection string.
Here are the things that I’ve tried:

I have tried creating a new MongoDB Atlas account with a different cloud provider and region/zone.
MongoDB Atlas has a connection rule in Windows Defender’s outbound rules. (Remote ports 27015-
27017). I guess this was created by MongoDB during install, so the firewall should not be an issue.
Whitelisted 0.0.0.0/0 ( a security risk, but there is no valuable data here).
Started using a password that doesn’t require url encoding (no special characters).
Here is my software list:
nodejs: v16.13.0
express: v4.18.1
mongoose: v6.5.2

I did read something about lowering the node version to fix it. If that’s the case, I’m willing to do that but what should it be lowered to?

MongoDB Compass connection string:
`mongodb+srv://brohjoe1:password@cluster0.4ross7o.mongodb.net/auth`

Here is the actual error:

```
C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:824
  const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                               ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an 
IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:824:32)
    at C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:10
    at C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1225:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:379:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\app.js:11:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-v2tectr-shard-00-01.4ross7o.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress {
          isIPv6: false,
          host: 'ac-v2tectr-shard-00-01.4ross7o.mongodb.net',
          port: 27017
        },
        address: 'ac-v2tectr-shard-00-01.4ross7o.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1097611983,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.239.246.213:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:302:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
        }
      },
      'ac-v2tectr-shard-00-02.4ross7o.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress {
          isIPv6: false,
          host: 'ac-v2tectr-shard-00-02.4ross7o.mongodb.net',
          port: 27017
        },
        address: 'ac-v2tectr-shard-00-02.4ross7o.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1097611977,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.232.109.33:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:302:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
        }
      },
      'ac-v2tectr-shard-00-00.4ross7o.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress {
          isIPv6: false,
          host: 'ac-v2tectr-shard-00-00.4ross7o.mongodb.net',
          port: 27017
        },
        address: 'ac-v2tectr-shard-00-00.4ross7o.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1097612045,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.238.72.187:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\brohj\WebstormProjects\Firebase\redEyeMedia\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:302:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
        }
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-bt7sor-shard-0',
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Comment: I changed the DNS server settings to Google's DNS IPv4 Servers...8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.  Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I finally connected to MongoDB Atlas.  After using my cell phone to tether to my computer, I was able to connect with no problems. At that point, I knew it was an ISP issue. To connect using your ISP's internet, you have to open port 27017 on your gateway device.  Search 'port forwarding' for your particular ISP to add port 27017 to the list of available ports.  It's not open by default for some ISPs like mine. Good coding!